# How to restrict the scale domain based on data, without encompassing all the data

Tags: vega-lite

I have a collection of data including datestamps, which will be plotted on the x-axis of a line graph. I would like to be able to restrict the x-axis so that only the last year's worth of data is visible by default, and panning will make the rest visible.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this in vega-lite.

- If I knew the date range in advance I could hard-code the domain, but the same spec will be used to generate graphs with different data.
- If I wanted to encompass all the dates, this is done by default.
- If I wanted to extend the domain so that it includes all the dates plus some other dates, this can also be done (using the `unionwith` interface).

Trying something like the following just results in an empty box.

```
      "scale": {
        "domain": { "expr": "[max(datum.dates) - 365, max(datum.dates)]" }
      }
```

Comment: Later asked slightly more successfully here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429932/set-domainmin-to-6-months-before-max-date-in-data