# Set domainMin to 6 months before max date in data

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following Vega-Lite chart:

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLFp2y9B46ZsAzC2lBkjbBjjcgXgwS0AYjgAVjCwkABfJSQjKF9-QPQggCYmVKgAZgBOaNijOBRUUCTg9Mzc-JBhQ18ITE8AazhyjOy8mJAcJE0SkAbm1pSKjurCqExEmgC2ys6lCBgkHGHQQbYWubGuiABPBCY2ZNKZ5JA09qquoyRZMjXtXvI2Iz20AG0L1NSADiykKlTEEAAwgrJwABsKCUQSQAEYoBFgQAxAAiACEAKLwrKo1IAdkJWOBWIAglkUZTgalQmScliQaicgSySDfsCxPCMSiMRzYaF4b80QBhMnAnJiSEgsn8i6QlEEtG-MTAtHw0Vk0IgAC6US6mDogmGIAAyl56AACADqcAaxlkltNezUhj2lpFDAQDEEvRopEtdzUlrR+kE7pFAHkAGoASTR-HhOQ9SAgdstTHdABkAOLipRqXrFUAMIznLC4fBEQvEdTKJDGiDUOiMFjsAiyCDKfg6WtqRM5fiFvQEZw0IwIOBqAD6UFTduneiYxvh08EbDnhrklCgEGI1UadwgTleCE+p0EmAc-SD578NDggjUWkEMBnqRB8JB09kSEnpjgABHBgGy0c0GCtW17SMR1nVdOB3hiUBZDYKZ+hcR9n3QQQKB-P84CTADgNA9AAAU4FkIwW2iKI9SQlQDDUNhlDvNgfHQHQGFsUwMKfLQUMNFxN3YWRp2HVpYggawvR9P1SFnLxuNopQnFuf9UA+WQfUEBQQT1HUlF9PZrw+dZHzgSYRN8cTfEwPZVi0AwryMYhQKUJhGK0aAGztADZB0NQDDIKSNJAAAPXV9SUZAjCaWz7JNJg4lMTA2GOQ12MaBg4C6CiAqC3wIv6Q1JwAVVkOgtGMuIEF0N9nh4h8+PQASaCEv05DEhqlDshz0CvBAcFeNyQENTBjS0UMr2qHR1xMdCmqwmpcN-SdCJ6hL+LYBADBGsaJvQXN8xqcgKKw0BXgfbj+rYxxji9Ts0DEKKQHeG8yA8Phpo4xSphUxaXxW-D1tGzb0GI2w6DkiTRqNE0RXnKTYjCmgQtAfaTVDGYI0RjN3VNa1TUtI6aKi0AYri7D7D8-L7kK2yaDKiq0NeooJzqmz-swrbBJoYTOs52Hxsx7rQb60bECG25AkWOcDtAJjkAMABZAwtA-VJ4X4EFIW1+EaKUN7QCQD7Cgob6QGQCKuea7QZN9Q15M47iNvFiGxuh0wkBRtGhYOkBPW9B3-TgFM0yk-V9QMkBChkQRSHqOXHjekBGLgVZZDUCipkjoA)

Currently, I have the scale set as follows:

```json
"scale": {"domainMin": "2021-06-01"}
```

However, what I really want is for the `domainMin` to be automatically calculated to be 6 months before the latest date in the `notification_date` field in the data.
I've looked at [aggregate](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/aggregate.html) and [expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/), but it's not exactly clear.

How can I get the maximum value of `notification_date` and subtract 6 months from it, and use that in `"domainMin"`?

**Edit**: To clarify, I don't want to `filter` the data. I want the user to be able to zoom out or pan to see the data outside the initial 6-month window. I get exactly what I want with `"scale": {"domainMin": "2021-06-01"}`, but this becomes out-of-date very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

A bit simpler approach to filter approximately the last six months of data might look like this:

```json
  "transform": [
    ...,
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "notification_date", "as": "last_date"}]},
    {"filter": "datum.notification_date > datum.last_date - 6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000"}
  ]
```

It makes use of the fact that dates are stored as millisecond time-stamps, and has the benefit that it will work across year boundaries.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp, I  should clarify that I don't want to filter the data. I want the full data to be available, I just want the scale set to the last 6 months initially. The user should have the option to zoom out or pan across to see previous data. `"scale": {"domainMin": "2021-06-01"}` gives me this, but will obviously become out-of-date quickly!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried giving `params` and `expr` to domainMin, but I was unable to use the data fields in `expr` through `datum`.

The 2nd approach I tried will work for you, in this you will need to make use of `joinaggregate/calculate/filter` transforms. You will manually gather the max year and max months and then use it to filter your data.

Below is the modified config or refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-B0tbUiey-ELegIzhoRgQcDUAH0oKm7dO9ExjXDp4I2HPDXJKFAIMQqg1bhAnC8EB8ToJMA4+kHz34aHBBGotIIYDOUsC4cDp7IkJPTHAACODANlo5oMFatr2kYjrOq6cBvNEoCyGwkx9C4j7PugggUD+f5wEmAHAaB6AAApwLIRgtlEkR6khjyCFAPpPFoEFQLshRGAAFMOXqUChhouJu7CyNOw5wAAlKYqZaBxsQAHJekwDj0XOjHMVerGYFACC6DAPE9HxAk0EJfpyGJTxSTEEBaLptgwIpBwqQooCqLIahsMod5sD46A6AwtimBhT5aMZplbqJ4nSTZflehp-pwLOXiBbRShODc-6oO8sg+oICjAnqLkgJIbAGEgZAeHwmlZScmG2XpjnKSYSg+bZSAAB7RW17XTnZ9BJQFkz0cFWEgHJRiNQ4LW+SAyCddZ3XTuNUSFaAalMb61UgEgTAQAZmB8XNvV6QNtj8BCVnbTFs0GMd9mnUNRX+FeJjoLxCCUAgt19TAD2WgAPJa72fQ1SnGJaABkENA4ZH1HeNloALzIzDB0feNk0mKl1RIBxr3vGsj5wBMIm+FFfSYLsKxaAYL3EKBShMAYo3QA2doAbIOhqAYZAxZ8nV0UoyBGI0viU9T6BMLEpiYGwRyGr5DQMHAnQUVzPO+J1FM0JOACqsh0LJnE-VFaUPiF6BhTQwnmabIDiyaV4IDgLwM-bRomqGmmdDo66vbVFvVLhv6ToRSgO6FbBfb+gThx7Wi5vm1TkBRWGgC8D6Begss+Eovtep2aAcvqShvDeFUFBQW3+YFZt1dhwf4WH9tUyaxG2HQfqkDL8foCK842TE7U0DFoCGpgxpaKG0wRgPGbuqa1qmpaic0SXoDC6L2H2Bz6t3JrYs63A+uG+g40myxdeB1bNuRZf7sT5798R9niAuzcgSdGXoDlZVVcmnNIK5tRpMW9JtBKD0Zaty0O3ceXcWhDxHofR+WhPRgPgSmNMNl9T6h1EoAoMhBDdz6KzSefQy4gGZnAFY7kKJDX1EAA) url:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "config": {
    "group": {"fill": "#e5e5e5"},
    "arc": {"fill": "#2b2c39"},
    "area": {"fill": "#2b2c39"},
    "line": {"stroke": "#2b2c39"},
    "path": {"stroke": "#2b2c39"},
    "rect": {"fill": "#2b2c39"},
    "shape": {"stroke": "#2b2c39"},
    "symbol": {"fill": "#2b2c39"},
    "range": {
      "category": [
        "#2283a2",
        "#003e6a",
        "#a1ce5e",
        "#FDBE13",
        "#F2727E",
        "#EA3F3F",
        "#25A9E0",
        "#F97A08",
        "#41BFB8",
        "#518DCA",
        "#9460A8",
        "#6F7D84",
        "#D1DCA5"
      ]
    }
  },
  "title": "South Western Sydney Cumulative and Daily COVID-19 Cases by LGA",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://davidwales.github.io/nsw-covid-19-data/confirmed_cases_table1_location.csv"
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {"field": "lhd_2010_name", "equal": "South Western Sydney"},
          {"not": {"field": "lga_name19", "equal": "Penrith"}}
        ]
      }
    },
    {"calculate": "utcyear(datum.notification_date)", "as": "yearNumber"},
    {"calculate": "utcmonth(datum.notification_date)", "as": "monthNumber"},
    {
      "window": [
        {"op": "count", "field": "notification_date", "as": "cumulative_count"}
      ],
      "frame": [null, 0]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"field": "monthNumber", "op": "max", "as": "max_month_count"},
        {"field": "yearNumber", "op": "max", "as": "max_year"}
      ]
    },
    {"calculate": "abs(datum.max_month_count-6)", "as": "min_month_count"},
    {
      "filter": "datum.min_month_count < datum.monthNumber && datum.max_year === datum.yearNumber"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "selection": {
        "date": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["x"]}
      },
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "field": "notification_date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "title": "Date"
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "lga_name19",
          "type": "nominal",
          "title": "LGA",
          "legend": {"orient": "top", "columns": 4}
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "count",
          "field": "lga_name19",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Cases",
          "axis": {"title": "Daily Cases by SWS LGA"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "field": "notification_date",
          "title": "Date",
          "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "max",
          "field": "cumulative_count",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "Cumulative Cases"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @wahab-memon. I've edited my question to clarify that I specifically don't want to use `filter`, as I want the user to be able to pan or zoom to see data outside the initial 6-month view. I get exactly this with `"scale": {"domainMin": "2021-06-01"}`, but obviously this becomes out-of-date quickly!

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite an answer to the question you asked, but if your data is reasonably up-to-date (that is, the most recent data point is close to the current date), you can do something like this:

```
"scale": { "domainMin": { "expr": "timeOffset('month', now(), -6)" } }
```

Comment: Ooh. That looks a bit closer to what I was looking for! Thanks!